# Can we use longlistselector inside a popup in Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, popup, longlistselector

How to use longlistselector inside a popup control?

If not possible, then any other way to show longlistselector/listbox as a popup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Page and simply put your LongListSelector in it.

For example (Page is called `MyPopupPage`):

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <con:LongListSelector x:Name="LongListSelector">
            <con:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </con:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </con:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

Then fill it with whatever you want (Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx)

In your MainPage (the page which should open the popup):
Create an object of type Popup like:

```
Popup LLSPopup = new Popup();
```

And create a Method to set the MyPopupPage as the overlay of the popup:

```
private void ShowPopup()
{
    MyPopupPage ovr = new MyPopupPage();
    this.LLSPopup.Child = ovr;
    this.LLSPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Its Not working :( I am not able to open a sample page inside popup in another popup.

Comment: Why what's happening/not happening? And why do you need 2 Popups?

Comment: Sorry.. its a typo
I am not able to open a sample page inside popup in another page. I created a page with a text block and in another page I did in same way as you(@Daniel) suggested, but its showing a blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

As a popup you can you **CustomMessageBox**. Instances of **CustomMessageBox** have property **Content**, that has no differences from the **Content** property of  any other content controls. So you can put there LongListSelector or ListBox or whatever you want (even Pivot and Panorama), than call **Show** method. CustomMessageBox will close if user'll click one of the 2 default buttons, but you can hide them (properties **IsLeftButtonEnabled** and **IsRightButtonEnabled**) and close CustomMessageBox by your own logic by calling  **Dismiss** method. There is a couple of useful events: the most useful is **Dismissed**, that raises right after CustomMessageBox get closed (dismissed), its handler contains DismissedEventArgs, that has result of users choiсe (right or left button was chosen, if they were on the screen) and of course sender (CustomMessageBox). If you want some logic after CustomMessageBox closing, use Dismissed event, Show method won't stop program flow.

This is the easiest way to show something. It's not a popup, but it behaves like it.

But if you wont to use popup ifself, there is Child property for you, put there Grid, and ListBox inside the Grid. But you have to set the values of the Width and Height of popup Child.